# Method for staking coins in Casper FFG

Tags: contract-deployment, proof-of-stake, casper

When Ethereum changes to a PoW/PoS hybrid (Casper FFG), how will the staking process work? I heard that there might be smart-contracts and you need to send your coins to the contract to stake the coins but how will the contract be official? That's what I heard.

The question is: how will I be able to stake my coins when the change to hybrid scheme comes?

[Casper FFG](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09437.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the details of the staking process there starts to be more and more high quality information available.

Here is flow chart how the validator works:

https://github.com/ethereum/casper/blob/master/VALIDATOR_GUIDE.md

Here is the current smart contract source code in Vyper language (not Solidity):

https://github.com/ethereum/casper/tree/master/casper/contracts

Comment: Ok so basically, people will deploy their own smart-contract containing codes for validating (staking) and they will send the coin to the contract.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few documents that explain that, and some repos you can visit:

- https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/01/introducing-casper-friendly-ghost/
- https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/24/understanding-serenity-part-i-abstraction/
- https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/28/understanding-serenity-part-2-casper/
- https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/03/05/serenity-poc2/

The proof of bet implemented on Casper is in essence the "parent" or a generalization of a particular case that will be the Satoshian PoW.

On the articles avobe, you can read and understand quite good how consensus is archieved and the main differences of PoC (or proof of bet) and the actual Proof of concepts) and obviously, how Casper works.

If you want to test it, you can do it [here](https://github.com/ethereum/cbc-casper)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer is about Casper cbc, which is not the same as Casper FFG

Comment: My bad mate, sorry, I don't know why i understood CBC :(